Ward identity for special conformal transformation in d dimensions
I am reading CFT from the yellow book ( "Conformal Field Theory" by Francesco, Mathieu, Sénéchal ). In section 4.3.2, they calculate three Ward identities corresponding to (i) translation invariance, (ii) rotation/Lorentz invariance, and (iii) dilation invariance. Note that they don't find Ward identity for special conformal invariance. They say: " ... are THE THREE Ward identities associated with conformal invariance."
This is confusing me. Here is my question:

Is there no Ward identity corresponding to special conformal transformation? Are there supposed to be just three ( and not four ) Ward identites in d dimensions ?

Let me give here slightly more background so that others can also learn something from my questions:
If an action S is invariant under a symmetry transformation, it leads to a conserved Noether current $J^a_{\mu}$ such that $\partial^{\mu} J^a_{\mu} = 0$. There is one such current for each symmetry transformation. So the index a iterates over all the symmetry transformations of action S. When we do path integral using this action S ( we are assuming that the path integral measure is also invariant under these symmetry transformations ) then we get a QFT. In a QFT, instead of a conserved current $J^a_{\mu}$ , we get a Ward identity on the correlation functions for each symmetry transformation of the action/measure.
A theory which has conformal invariance has 4 independent symmetry tranformations, which are (i) translations, (ii) rotations and/or Lorentz transformations, (iii) dilations, and (iv) special conformal transformations. So I would expect 4 Ward identities. But the book mentions only three Ward identities.
Also, in 2 dimensions, the group of conformal invariance is much different than in general dimension d. I haven't reached the d =2 case in the book yet. So I am emphasizing the general dimension d in my question.
